# Why is the menu JavaScript effect not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was developing a menu structure and tried to make it stay on the page even after scrolling down from top position. But it's not working, seems I am making a mistake but can't figure out what went wrong.

This is what I have in `menu.js` (the JavaScript file for menu effect):

```
$(function(){

var menu = $('#menu'),
    pos = menu.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the link for the stylesheet: http://www.neo4evr.com/templates/splash1/css/style.css

Is there anything wrong in the JavaScript (`menu.js`)?

Comment: Codereview is for reviews of working code. Not for getting help to get code to work. For questions like this, you should go to Stack Overflow (where I'll now move this question).

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing this in css only (using position: fixed; on the menu container)?

Answer (score 1):

Your outer anonymous function is declared but not executed, so nothing really happens. In order to execute the outer function, you should change the last line into `})();`